# how to select store procedure function genereteID in codeigniter?

Tags: php, function, codeigniter, stored-procedures, mysqli

I want to make a generated ID to use the function store procedure, but I am confused how to display generete ID using CodeIgniter.

Generete ID in store procedure function 'PenjualanGenIdFunc':

```
BEGIN
DECLARE kodebaru CHAR(15);
DECLARE urut INT;
SET urut = IF(nomer IS NULL, 1, nomer + 1);
SET kodebaru = CONCAT("PJL", LPAD(urut, 12, 0));
RETURN kodebaru;
END
```

I call in model with the code:

```
function getKodePenjualan(){
    $query = $this->db->query("select PenjualanGenIdFunc('kodebaru') AS kodepenjualan");
    return $query->row_array();
}
```

in controller :

```
$data['kodepenjualan'] = $this->mwebsite->getKodePenjualan();
```

and in view :

```
<?php echo $kodepenjualan['kodepenjualan'];?>
```

From the above code, generate ID already show with code: PJL000000000001, but when I will buy again. the code would not be PJL000000000002, PJL000000000003 and etc.

how to call a store procedure function for generete id ??
Please help me

Answer (score 0):

First, if you want to call a SP, you need to call like this

$this->db->query("call PenjualanGenIdFunc()");

In your SP you must have something like this

CREATE PROCEDURE My_Insert
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO My_Table (col1)
    VALUES (@col1)

```
SELECT @new_identity = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

SELECT @new_identity AS id

RETURN
```

END

but if you want to get the last id insert using CI, you can use

$this->db->insert('table', array('value1' => $value1));

return $this->db->insert_id();